# Sharepoint-app and chrome having issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, chrome

I was creating my SharePoint Online apps as usual in Visual Studio this morning, and the app wont run if I don't exit Chrome. I get an error saying:

> Cannot attach application to 'chrome.exe' (PID:95108), the debugger was unable to find registration for the target application, if the problem persists try uninstalling and then reinstalling this application.

What is the cause of this issue? Did anyone have this problem before?

Comment: Same issue - glad I'm not the only one seeing this. Not sure what the cause is, but changing the Start Action in the project properties to "Internet Explorer" at least allowed me to continue working for now.

Comment: Any luck? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Garima Sorry, I haven't been able to find a solution to this, I've just been using internet explorer instead. It's weird though, I've never had this problem before.

Comment: @Somethingcool123 yes same here. Weird!